# Getting an error when trying to compile a c file using gcc

Tags: c

I tried looking everywhere to see if theres an answer but it seems that people have encountered the similar problem but none of the solutions that I read have worked.

Im using gcc as my compiler

I am familiar with c++ but never encountered a problem like this on c++, but, Im just trying to do a simple printf and scanf for user input and printing out the results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;

    printf("Enter two integers: \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);

    printf("your two integers are: %d and %d \n", num1,num2 );

return 0;
}
```

the error that I get in the terminal:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

thank you in advanced!

Comment: What is the exact command you are using?

Comment: The error message mentions clang. Are you sure you're using gcc?

Comment: gcc -c main.c , gcc -o main main.c, and i tried gcc -o main main.o ,still same error

Comment: @sneep `gcc` might be a symlink to `clang`, for compatibility.

Comment: can you tell the gcc version. gcc --version

Comment: @ArunKuttiyaraVarghese Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, and it might have been an outdated gcc, so I just typed these commands in the terminal and it fixed it.

```
brew update

brew install gcc

brew cleanup
```

Thank you for your help. Honestly I am not sure if it was that fixed it but that that is the only thing that I ran.